# Why are my DNX-based unit tests unable to resolve System dependencies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

I'm writing up a DNX-based portable class library that I want to be used on all platforms. Here is its `project.json`:

```
{
    "title": "flavor.net",

    "dependencies": {
        "Be.IO": "1.0.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259": {
            "frameworkAssemblies": {
                "System.Collections": { "type": "build" },
                "System.IO": { "type": "build" },
                "System.Linq": { "type": "build" },
                "System.Runtime": { "type": "build" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the unit tests' `project.json` (I'm using the [xUnit.net](http://xunit.github.io/) testing framework):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "flavor.net": "",
        "VideoLibrary": "1.3.3",
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
    },
    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to build this, I'm getting several errors saying things like `The dependency fx/System.Collections could not be resolved` for all of the `System` dependencies in the first file. The weird thing is, that project itself seems to be building fine, but it's the unit test project that is causing errors.

Here's a screenshot for extra clarity:

[image]

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it? I'm using VS 2015 Update 1 and my DNX version is 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing those references in the test project's project.json file. Example : https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.Test/project.json